# Iteratively add to pandas panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel, hdf5

I need to iteratively add dataframes to a panel since the data is too large to be held in memory.

A sample code reads like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('io.hdf.default_format','table')
store = pd.HDFStore('testA.h5')

base = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=['a','b','c'])
store['A'] = pd.Panel({0:base})
store['A'][1] = base
print store['A'][1]
```

This gives the error `KeyError: u'no item named 1'`. So the second dataframe has not been added!!!

Why is this?

Comment: Are you trying to append them to an `HDFStore` iteratively? Appending to a Panel will always be in memory, so it's not totally clear what you mean. For example, just iteratively appending to a Panel will of course result in an in-memory Panel with your frames.

Comment: their are example about appending to a HDFStore panel, but you need to use append and you have to append complete panels

Comment: So I can't store a panel and then append dataframes to that panel whilst it is still in hdf5 then?

Comment: no, you need to store a full panel otherwise how would you know what indexer to use? (eg where to put it in the panel). the panel can of course only contain a single frame eg Panel({ 'foo' : a_frame })

Comment: True, ok thanks. I've implemented that!